# calling convention regarding asmlinkage

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, x86-64, calling-convention

I thought calling a function with asmlinkage modifier needs to push all argument to stack, until I was baffled by the following in Linux kernel source (3.16).

source in entry_64.S [link](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S?v=3.16#L1357)

```
 movq %rsp,%rdi
 call sync_regs
```

Definition of `sync_regs` in `arch/x86/kernel/traps.c`:

```
asmlinkage __visible notrace struct pt_regs *sync_regs(struct pt_regs *eregs)
{
 struct pt_regs *regs = task_pt_regs(current);
 *regs = *eregs;
 return regs;
}
```

Shouldn't it need to push `%rdi`/`%rsp` to stack?

Answer/takeaway: Thanks to @Jester, the answer I summarize below:

> - NOTE! On x86-64, all the arguments are in registers, so this
> - only matters on a 32-bit kernel." [[linux src comment](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h)]

Comment: 64 bit calling convention uses registers for the first few arguments. Read the abi docs.

Comment: I thought that was for default setting (wo asmlinkage)... so for x_86_64, asmlikage will NOT assume argument on stack?... or asmlinkage is only for 32 bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/asmlinkage says `asmlinkage` means args are always pushed on the stack.  This is probably an old doc.  32bit i386 Linux uses a register calling convention (`regparm`) inside the kernel, and `asmlinkage` really means "follow the standard ABI, whatever it is".  So the FAQ only applies to i386.

For x86-64 (and any other architecture that doesn't override it), `asmlinkage` is defined to be empty, or `extern "C"` in c++ code. For 32 bit x86 it is defined as `regparm(0)`.  (Thanks, Jester, for digging in the header files.)

Comment: Yeah, doc may be wrong. But the source never is :)  For x86-64 (and any other architecture that doesn't override it), `asmlinkage` is defined to be empty, or `extern "C"` in c++ code. For 32 bit x86 it is defined as `regparm(0)`.

Comment: Thanks @Jester.  That confirms my guess that i386 Linux builds with `regparm` for internal functions, and only uses the "standard" registers-on-the-stack ABI when needed.

Comment: @Jester, could you provide evidence for your statement: 

" For x86-64 (and any other architecture that doesn't override it), asmlinkage is defined to be empty"

Comment: Yes, see [include/linux/linkage.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/linkage.h) and [include/asm-generic/linkage.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/asm-generic/linkage.h) and [arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/linkage.h)